# Add missing element in list of DateTimeOffset in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating time buckets of 60 minutes each. This is data that is returned from a Postgres query.

the duration that is being considered for creating buckets is like 1 day, 7 days.

there is an instance when there are missing buckets. to fill those I am creating a method that will identify the missing point and will be added in the series.

This method is built with C#.

to demonstrate logic, I have created a sample.

```
DateTimeOffset startTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), startTargetTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
DateTimeOffset endTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
int interval = 60;
List<DateTimeOffset> series = new List<DateTimeOffset>();
List<DateTimeOffset> target = new List<DateTimeOffset>(); // this will be the database values

int cntr = 0;
while(startTime < endTime)
{
    startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(interval);
    if (cntr % 2 == 0)
    {
        target.Add(startTime) ;
    }
    cntr++;
}

while (startTargetTime < endTime)
{
    startTargetTime = startTargetTime.AddMinutes(interval);
    series.Add(startTargetTime);
}

if(target.Count != series.Count)
{
    foreach (var item in series)
    {
        if(!target.Exists(val => val == item))
        {
            target.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The current problem is even though the same item exists it is still added in the target list. what could be the problem.

Are there more efficient ways to make the comparison and add the missing items?

Comment: Timezones, minutes and seconds, all of this can differ. If I were you, I would start with making sure both DB and code dates are in utc. I would remove hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

Comment: @HirasawaYui your comments are valid, for this case the format of date is the same in database and in C# so it should be fine.

Comment: If you want all the buckets, why involve the database at all? Just create the buckets you want.

Comment: ... why not create the "missing" series entries as part of the database query?  Postgre has [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html).  Also, `DateTime.Now.AddXXX` is (almost certainly) wrong; if the machine is using a timezone with DST, you're going to get nonexistent times.  Whether you should be using `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`, or something more exotic with NodaTime will depend on whether you're trying to report on an exact 24-hour period, or the local "day", respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This portion of your code, which populates `series`, is independent of anything going on in `target`.  It just adds all values in the interval.

```
while (startTargetTime < endTime)
{
    startTargetTime = startTargetTime.AddMinutes(interval);
    series.Add(startTargetTime);
}
```

To fix it, just do a check against whether the value already exists in `target`:

```
while (startTargetTime < endTime) {
    startTargetTime = startTargetTime.AddMinutes(interval);
    if (!target.Contains(startTargetTime)) {
        series.Add(startTargetTime);
    }
}
```